# Accessing MySQL field values from mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, javascript, calendar

I have written a calendar implementation, which is working, but displays only one set of data, I'm trying to make it appear all of the data in my select query:

```
$events = '';
$query = mysql_query('SELECT event_id, event_type, time, date, location, home_or_away, team_id FROM event WHERE date = "'.$deets.'"'); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num_rows > 0) {
$events .= '<div id="eventsControl"><button onMouseDown="overlay()">Close</button><br /><br /><b> ' . $deets . '</b><br /><br /></div>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

I know it has to do with something with this, but I don't know exactly what code to imply to get 'event_type', 'time' and etc

```
$desc = $row['event_id'] ;

$events .= '<div id="eventsBody">' . $desc . '<br /> <hr><br /></div>';
}
}
echo $events;
?>
```

Comment: `$event_type = $row['event_type'];` and BTW your query is prone to SQL injections

Comment: `$row['event_type'], $row['location']`, etc...  To see what is in `$row`, do `print_r($row)`

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions in new code as they are deprecated. See question: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your columns as keys in the array. So to have time, use $row['time'] and so on.

For showing multiple data, try concatenating

$desc = $row['time'] .$row['event_type']

Comment: hello thanks for the advice, its now displaying more than one set of data, but now theres error
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo  $row['event_id'] ;
echo  $row['event_type'];
$events .= '<div id="eventsBody">' . $query .   '<br /> <hr><br /></div>';
}

}
echo $events;
saying that 344game
Close

5/22/2013

Resource id #5 - which is rather confusing and I was also wondering if you know how to space the data with a comma

Comment: Modify the body of the while as: { $events .= '<div id="eventsBody">' .$row['event_id'] .', ' .$row['event_type'] .'<br/><hr><br /></div>'; } In this case you will have the id and type inside div, and the resource number will not show.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
$time  = $row['time']
```

etc?
I'm not sure I've got your point

Comment: basically i want it to display more than just the event_id. I want to display all the other fields ('event_type' , 'time' and etc). I tryed the other pieces of code doesnt work still :( any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do but if you are trying to display all columns, you can use a foreach loop

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     foreach($row as $key=>$value)
      {
        echo("<b>$key</b>$value<br/>");
      }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the help it actually partly works, for some reason its displaying them twice first number value e.g 1 12:00, then 'time12:00' do you know why that is and also it still has reference id #5

Comment: this is by design. either use mysql_fetch_assoc or pass MYSQL_ASSOC as second parameter to mysql_fetch_array:  

  mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);